# Quickly find if point lies between 2 non-intersecting segments?

Tags: algorithms

Let's say we know that point P(x1, y1) lies in between Xa and Xb on the cartesian coordinate system. How to quickly check if it is contained within 2 non-intersecting segments that originate from line Xa and terminate at Xb?

Simply comparing their equations to the coordinate of point takes at most 2 checks if P is in between, is there a way to do it within just 1 check?

for example: if P is not in between A or B then it is not contained else - contained

```
|    |
|\   |
| \  |
|  \ |  Diagonal segment A (negative slope)
|   \|
| *P |
|    |
|----|  Horizontal segment B (y = c)
|    |                              
Xa   Xb
```

Yes, it can be represented as a binary search tree

```
  A
 /
B
```

But in my particular case there are always have to be 2 rays and 2 checks will still need to be performed (at most) (plus, BST is not efficient with just 2 elements)

Maybe I can extend the lines further and check if point is in between two rays, is this possible? Or something like that.

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of reducing the number of tests here? Just to get some context.

Comment: @DannyBirch It's about checking whether point lies in a polygon or not at runtime(the slabs algorythm) Project initially started with concave polygons in mind, but having switched to just convex, binary search trees are no longer efficient (there is always 2 elements), so I need to optimize. It's like a red flag in the corner of my eyes. The check has to be done 400 times a frame, and there are lots of Xa and Xbs for different points :/   Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=ax+b$ and $y=cx+d$ the equations of the lines that contain the segments.

The easy solution is

```
if ((y1>a*x1+b) and (y1<c*x1+d)) then do something;
```

provided that the line $y=ax+b$ is "below" and $y=cx+d$ is "above".

You want to avoid two checks. The following solution involves only one check, and removes the necessity of knowing which line is above and which below:

```
if ( (a*x1+b-y1)*(c*x1+d-y1) < 0 ) then do something;
```

The idea behind this is that if the product of two numbers is negative, then these numbers has different sign. That is, the point is "over" one line and "under" the other one.

Comment: You're welcome :)